# The windows "open" function on folders disappeared

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I don't know how it happened, but when I right-click on a folder, the "open" action doesn't show up any more. Instead of this, I have the default action set to "Read with windows player".

How can I recover the "open" action ?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Windows 7 Start Menu, right click on the Windows Explorer shortcut (typically store inside All Programs -> Accessories) and then select Properties.
2. In the Target text box under Shortcut tab, change the value to one of the following to open either Documents or Computer by default.

   - **To make *Explorer* the default enter:**

     ```
     %windir%\explorer.exe
     ```
   - **To make *Documents* the default folder to open in Windows Explorer upon launching:**

     ```
     %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n,::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
     ```
   - **To make *Computer* the default folder to open in Windows Explorer upon launching:**

     ```
     %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
     ```
3. Click OK when done.

Windows 7 Explorer will now open Documents or Computer directly, skipping and bypassing Libraries, depends on what you set or configure on initial run. There are more special objects and folders that Windows Explorer can open directly to.

Windows XP

Try this

Open My Computer window. 
• Click Tools, Folder Options, then click File Types.

• From the list, locate the entry FOLDER with extension of (NONE).

• Click Advanced, select Explore, then Set Default

• Click OK and close the dialog. To accomplish this via the Registry: •Open Regedit.exe and navigate to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell

•In the right pane, set the value of (default) to explore

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it was on Windows XP.

Comment: Sorry it was tagged XP

Comment: @Kevin this should be an answer.